# Acer or Dell? Which of these laptops is better to set dual boot system?

Tags: laptop, linux, windows

I'm looking for laptops to buy. In my country,the best choices for a while are **`Dell G5 5590`** and **`Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315-52`**.So, having any experience using these brands' products I need to know how dual boot system will run in each of these laptops.

---

*The following questions interest me too so I leave their here by its [importance](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/odyssey#manualsDownloads)*:

`Will one or both be unbootable after setting as dual boot( Windows and Linux)? After installation successful, what are the possible issues which I'll deal with?`

**Ps**: take a look at the page 6 of the Samsung's Odyssey manual if its relevant to you and leave a comment about it.

---

So, which of these two laptops is **better to run Linux distros setting multiple boot**?

Please,let me know what are your experiences using Linux alongside Windows in that specific laptops models.

**NOTICE**:I want to buy one of the two models I've mentioned.

Comment: I haven't used either of these laptops but I expect that they both work the same way for dual booting. You should look up the user manual for each and ensure that there is a BIOS setting for turning off secure boot in case you need to. Everything else going smoothly depends on the Linux Distro & Boot Manager you choose to install and *how* you install them. Pretty much every laptop with an Intel CPU has the same EFI-based boot capabilities, so the BIOS features & the layout of preinstalled partitions are the only things the brand will affect.

Comment: Of course, you are also responsible for any issues that the Linux install has, since most laptops do not officially support Linux and drivers for their components may be missing features or just not exist. On the Windows side, nothing will be different if you set up your boot manager to correctly boot with EFI. Once again, dual-boot problems you will encounter are significantly dependent on the specific changes you make to the laptop and its partitions, booting problems are not really dependent on the laptop itself.

Comment: @Romen a few days ago I've talked with a Samsung's employee and he said me that the BIOS may damage if I install Linux with Windows so that the laptop can't boot. It seems I can brick this specific laptop and their manual(https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/odyssey#manualsDownloads), page 6, recommend the user to use only Windows. So, I discarded the possibilities to getting the Odyssey 2.

Comment: In other hand, Dell and Acer do not "lock" the user to just use Windows OS in their products. I want a laptop which is more complete and free. @oldfred gave me relevant informations about brands support comparison: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/vendors/